# Ihow to merge two flat files have different data type in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm a newbie of ssis and still learning about this. I have a small question for you guys(but its big question for me). The questions are

 
Q1:
 
I've two flat files which contains different data type and columns, how do I merge this into one flat file with header in ssis? I done some research about Union All but the condition of Union All is two of the flat file must have the same data type.. 
I've tried the merge join and its not working (may be I've done something wrong)

Please advise. Many thanks!

Q2:
 
Flat File one (A Line)
House Number | Additional Column1 | Additional Column2 
 
1  | NULL        |             NULL

Flat File Two (B Line)
House Number |  Boy   |   Girl |   Parent Name
1    |          2      |   1      |    Jenni
1    |          1    |     1     |     Marry

Now I want my final Flat file
A, "1" 
B, "1", "2", "1", "Jenni"
B, "1", "1", "1", "Marry"

But when I use Union All I got something different from what I expect...
Please Advise

Comment: You can use Data Conversion to convert one of the file's data type.

Comment: merge as in total rows (UNION one on top of the other) or total columns (JOIN - side by side).

Comment: Thanks guys! I will try this and let you guys know how it go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 2 sources have different columns, you could try to use Derived Column transforms to create additional columns. This will make the number of columns equal for all 2 sources. Next, you could use a Union All transform to combine input from all sources, and then write to your flat file.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I will try this and let you know how it go

Comment: Hi Rahul,

Now I have two flat files and I need more advise. I've post more questions above

Comment: and please make also answer up if it helps :)

Comment: Yes Rahul. I'm trying to combine two flat files with one primary key. The primary key of this two flat file is house number. And I don't want additional columns to be in my final flat file. Thank you so much for your help so far! :)